# How to configure Django database using Heroku?

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm using Heroku with Django.

The database is configured in settings.py this way, using the [dj-database-url module](https://crate.io/packages/dj-database-url):

`DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config()}`

How can I do to add additional parameters, for example ATOMIC_REQUESTS? In a "normal" case I would do like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'mydatabase',
        'USER': 'mydatabaseuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypassword',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
        'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True,
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DATABASES is just a dictionary: you can add the relevant settings after the initial configuration.

```
DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config()}
DATABASES['default']['ATOMIC_REQUESTS'] = True
```